# Update several Tbl Fields based on Start/End Dates

Tags: ms-access-2016

Good day to everyone! Hope all is well!

I am looking to run an update query or a group of queries that looks at my Date_Start and Date_End to determine if the Units (quantity of the respective record) fall in my defined current quarter 1/2/3/4 from another table (this table is a master table I’m using to provide the dates that I need to consider for defining the quarters).

I’ve been able to create queries that do this and then join them together to basically display the units out by quarter based on their respective start/end dates. The problem I am running into is this process takes a decent amount of time for the queries to populate that will drastically effect other processes down the line.

Thus we get to my desire. I am trying to no avail to create an update query that will update the quarter fields in my table based off of the queries I built to determine if the records start/end date fall in the respective quarter. I figure that running this update when records change will be an ok run time vs when I’m running reports or running an email script for the reports.

I have tried pulling in the table and query, joining them as equal on ID (the query pulls in the table's IDs), and selecting my field “CQ1” from the table, and setting the Update ether the respective field from the table or the query (which is the same as the field in the table).

All I get are the current values of the field in the data sheet view and an error of “Operation must use an updateable query.”

I have even tried placing a zero to see if that would do it with no luck. I have verified that all the fields are the same data type.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apologies to everyone.....I think my conscious brain was trying to overly complicate the process and while talking to a buddy about my issue distractedly created a new update query that worked. It all tied down to that I forgot to put a criteria on my quarter filed of is not null I believe. Thanks for anyone that has read this and is responding while I’m typing this or for those of you formulating a response.